# How to enable syntax errors/warnings highlighting in atom

Tags: atom-editor

So I was using Aptana Studio before, and now I switched to Atom.

And I got used to Aptana's errors and warnings highlighting.
For example if I forgot `;` after declaration of a varible, or wrong brackets and etc...

In Atom I don't see any errors/warnings highlighting at all. Is it even possible to enable it in stock Atom, or should I download any additional packages?

P.S. I'm working with JS/JQuery/Node/PHP/HTML

Comment: I use jshint for JavaScript and / or jQuery.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, looks like Linter does the job: https://atom.io/packages/linter

Comment: Linter is broken on Ubuntu 16.04 atom version 1.15.0 x64

Comment: Very frustrating that I have to install a whole php engine on my desktop to get `linter-php` to show issues. Other packages do this naively. Atom is really lacking in certain areas.

Comment: Doesn't look like `linter` supports Javascript natively - another package is required to add support. As for which package that is, I have no idea......

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs use `linter-jshint` and `linter-eslint`. After installation of `linter-jshint`enable `Lint Inline Java Script` options from settings of this plugin.

Comment: I see, @VSB - thanks! Don't eslint and jshint require a per-project settings file though?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs I think they don't. However I have problems with htmls as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58442453/1080355.